# Quiero empezar a practicar mi código en c++ pero no sé que aplicación en el PC debo instalar

Tags: c++

Quiero empezar a practicar código en c++ pero no sé qué clase de aplicación debo instalar en el PC para poder empezar

Comment: Cualquier IDE que soporte c++

Comment: Cualquier compilador de c++ y un editor de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Community es un IDE que tiene todo lo que ocupas, si se te hace muy pesado prueba Visual Studio Code que es un editor de código que también es muy bueno

Comment: Ops, no lo sabía, gracias por el aviso